# How to convert an unorganized array into an grouped array by id

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to create an array that contains objects with an id and amount, grouped by id. The ids needs to be unique. So if there is 2 objects with same id, the amount will be added.

I can do it with nested for-loops, but I find this solution inelegant and huge. Is there a more efficient or cleaner way of doing it?

```js
var bigArray = [];

// big Array has is the source, it has all the objects
// let's give it 4 sample objects
var object1 = {
  id: 1,
  amount: 50
}
var object2 = {
  id: 2,
  amount: 50
}
var object3 = {
  id: 1,
  amount: 150
}
var object4 = {
id: 2,
amount:100
}
bigArray.push(object1,object2,object3,object4);


// organizedArray is the array that has unique ids with added sum. this is what I'm trying to get

var organizedArray = [];
organizedArray.push(object1);

for(var i = 1; i < bigArray.length; i++ ) {
  // a boolean to keep track whether the object was added
  var added = false;
  for (var j = 0; j < organizedArray.length; j++){
    if (organizedArray[j].id === bigArray[i].id) {
      organizedArray[j].amount += bigArray[i].amount;
      added = true;
    }
  }
  if (!added){
    // it has object with new id, push it to the array
    organizedArray.push(bigArray[i]);
  } 
}
console.log(organizedArray);
```

Comment: As a follow up to my original question, my original code is probably fast enough for most. However, we can simply opt to use .find() instead of creating a nested for-loop, it'll likely have the same performance, but the code is cleaner that way imo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than an organized array, how about a single object whose keys are the ids and values are the sums.

```js
var bigArray = [
  { id: 1, amount: 50 },
  { id: 2, amount: 50 },
  { id: 1, amount: 150 },
  { id: 2, amount: 100 }
];

let total = {}
bigArray.forEach(obj => {
  total[obj.id] = (total[obj.id] || 0) + obj.amount;
});

console.log(total);
```

If you really need to convert this to an array of objects then you can map the keys to objects of your choosing like this:

```js
var bigArray = [
  { id: 1, amount: 50 },
  { id: 2, amount: 50 },
  { id: 1, amount: 150 },
  { id: 2, amount: 100 }
];

let total = {}
bigArray.forEach(obj => {
  total[obj.id] = (total[obj.id] || 0) + obj.amount;
});

console.log(total);


// If you need the organized array:
let organizedArray = Object.keys(total).map(key => ({ id: key, amount: total[key] }));

console.log(organizedArray);
```

Comment: coming back to this question after a few years, I like your answer the most. This answer would also give much better performance if the array is really big, since it uses javascript Object which more or less act as a hash for significantly faster lookup

Answer (score 2):

You can definitly make it cleaner and shorter by using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), not sure about efficiency though, i would say a traditional `for` loop is more efficient :

```js
var bigArray = [];

var object1 = {id: 1, amount: 50}
var object2 = {id: 2, amount: 50}
var object3 = {id: 1, amount: 150}
var object4 = {id: 2, amount: 100}

bigArray.push(object1, object2, object3, object4);

var organizedArray = bigArray.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  // check if the object is in the accumulator
  const ndx = acc.findIndex(e => e.id === curr.id);
  
  if(ndx > -1) // add the amount if it exists
    acc[ndx].amount += curr.amount;
  else // push the object to the array if doesn't
    acc.push(curr);
    
   return acc;
}, []);

console.log(organizedArray)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, it is definitely shorter. I'm not too familiar with reduce but I'll try it

Answer (score -1):

```
 function getUniqueSums(array) {
  const uniqueElements = [];
  const arrayLength = array.length;

  for(let index = 0; index < arrayLength; index++) {

    const element = array[index];
    const id = element.id;

    const uniqueElement = findElementByPropertyValue(uniqueElements, 'id', id);

    if (uniqueElement !== null) {
      uniqueElement.amount += element.amount;
      continue;
    }

    uniqueElements.push(element);

  }

  return uniqueElements;

}

function findElementByPropertyValue(array, property, expectedValue) {

  const arrayLength = array.length;

  for(let index = 0; index < arrayLength; index++) {

    const element = array[index];
    const value = element[property];

    if (value !== expectedValue) {
      continue;
    }

    return element;

  }

  return null;

}
```

This is an untested code. You will be able to understand the logic. Logic is almost same yours. But, perhaps a more readable code.